# How to check if the sum 8 files with unlimited natural numbers stored in them is divisible by 8?

Tags: algorithm, logic

I had this question in an interview and as expected I wasn't able to answer it. I gave the interviewer a brute fore approach which was:

1. Add the numbers in each file.
2. Sum the numbers in each file and finally check if its divisible by 8.

At the same time I told him about the cons of this approach like Integer overflow and memory issues.

Anyways I tried hard to think but didn't success because I don't encounter these type of problems till now.

How can I solve above problem and how to develop my thinking process to solve problems like these? are there any resources out there which I could use?

Comment: (Applying for a paid employment?) First, pin the representation of those `unlimited natural numbers`. Compute the sum modulo some convenient number - for numbers in decimal representation, 1000 would do.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the nature of this problem, you are going to need to check every number in the files. This means that brute force is basically the only way to do this. However, there are ways of making it more memory efficient, and less prone to memory leaks. Here is a breakdown of a simple algorithm to reduce space complexity in pseudocode:

```
Read n integers into array
buffer[ len(array) ] = int array
total = 0

for integer i in array:
    if total % 8 == 0:
        total = 0
        remove all elements in buffer from array
    else
        buffer.append(i)
        total += i
    fi
end for
```

Using this algorithm, you sum numbers until you can divide them by 8, at which point you can remove all of those numbers from your buffer and read in more. For a small number like 8 this is perfectly fine, especially with very small or very large data files. I want to note though, that there does exist a set of numbers where no consecutive subarray will be divisible by 8. In other words, worst case space complexity is still O(n). However, this is most definitely not average case.

If you want better space complexity, you need to sacrifice just a wee bit of time, and add a little bit more complexity to your code. I won't get into any pseudocode for this, but essentially you need to match numbers (or sets of numbers) with corresponding modulus values. For example, the sum of two integers n and m is divisible by 8 iff (n%8) + (m%8) == 0,8. Example: 5 and 3, 17 and 15, 12 and 12.

There is nothing you can do to get the time complexity better than O(n), but if it is an option you can split the work up using multiple threads or processes.

Comment: I think it's not simple like that. For example, 2 + 2 + 4 or 1 + 2 + 5.

Comment: I fear this is not correct infact I gave him generator based solution and he was not convinced at last he told me you could apply divide and conquer but I didn't get it.

Comment: @khôinguyễn Are you talking about the example at the bottom? It is meant to be applied to 2 integers, not more. It was just a basic example, obviously the same logic can be applied to sets of integers.

Comment: @CodeYogi I can't know exactly what your interviewer expected, but the information here is correct. Did he expect you to use a parallel computing approach maybe?

Comment: @JacobH this definitely is not the answer lets wait for some other answers.

Comment: @CodeYogi maybe you can view my opinion in 2nd answer below.

Answer (score 1):

For the first time I read your question, I think about Longest non-contiguous subsequence divisible by k. However, it can't solve this big data.

In my opinion, you can solve this by count the frequency of remainders instead of sum all of input number. You just need an array of 8 element (corresponding to 0 to 7) to store these frequencies and check if the sum (i * array[i], i from 0 to 7) is divisible by 8.

However, maybe the number of numbers is too big. You can note that every number multiply 8 surely divisible by 8. So when counting the frequencies, if any elements in frequency array is up to 8, you can reset it to 0. One more, you can forget about 0-th element of array since it already divisible by 8. Finally, take the sum of (i * array[i], i from 1 to 7) then check if it divisible by 8.

```
Init array[8] by all 0.

while (there is number remain) 
    read a number tmp
    array[tmp % 8]++;
    if (array[tmp%8] == 8)
        array[tmp%8] = 0
sum = 0
for (i from 1 to 7)
    sum += array[i] * i
if sum % 8 == 0
    output yes
else
    output no
```

Comment: (Much) Too complicated, but based on an applicable principle.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save memory by not storing sum of all numbers, you can just `%` each number by 8 and sum each remainder. Finally, check if this final sum of remainders is divisible by 8.

If possible, you can also apply divisibility of 8 rule which states:

> A number is divisible by 8 if its last 3 digits are divisible by 8.

So you can perhaps factor that in somehow. Refer to @greybeard's comment below.

Comment: `A number is divisible by 8 if its [3 least significant decimal] digits are divisible by 8.` True: one thousand is 0 mod 8 (8*5³). `So for each number n you can n & (2048 - 1) => n & 2047 to get the last 3 digits` try that with 3000.

Answer (score 0):

`…how to develop my thinking process to solve problems`
Exercise, get used to *testing* and *presenting* solutions to problems. Don't force single problems: put them on the backburner.
(Exams/interviews are special - letting the interviewer in on your thoughts is the way to go. Found no really appropriate place on SE for interview (meta-)questions & advice.)

First, make *sure* you know enough about the problem to start solving it - here: input representation.
Figure out what is relevant (natural numbers, potentially huge&numerous, divisibility by a power of 2 (allowing to ignore but a few least significant digits with even bases))
and what is not (multiple files, number of files identical to number to check divisibility for).
If you don't "see" an approach, try to define smaller problem instances (divisibility of one natural - trivial; of sum of two naturals - ditto; of a gazillion: what about overflow (nothing with a binary computer, or using modulus explicitly); of humongous numbers - don't even construct a machine representation of them, go directly for their remainder if divided by the number to check divisibility for).
Refrain from introducing intricacies for the sake of efficiency before there is evidence a simple solution will not do.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to quickly to find out whether an int number is divisible by 8 is to shift it 3 bits to right and then 3 bits to left, and check whether the number is the same as before. Divisible by 8 means it must be 3 times divisible by 2. One shift to right means divide by 2. Here is an example in C++:

```
int x = ...;
int tmp = (x >> 3);
tmp = (tmp << 3);
if (tmp == x)
    cout << "divisible by 8 \n";
else
    cout << "not divisible by 8 \n";
```

Shifting is much faster then division or modulo division.
Another way is to apply bitwise & operator:

```
const unsigned int mask8 = 0xFFF8;
int x = ...
if( (x & mask8) == x )
  cout << "x is divisible by 8" << endl;
else
   cout << "x is not divisible by 8" << endl;
```

Now to the problem: I think you can ignore overflows and just add all numbers in each file. When resulting numbers are divisible by 8, the sums are divisible by 8. To chekc the divisibility we do not need the correct sums (they can be huge numbers), we can just check the numbers that are left after overflows.